# Rewrite Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default results in unable to find

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, autoloader

I'm trying to rewrite a class, although it gives an error in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract` telling me the class `Namespace_FormValidator_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default` does not exist in `Mage_Core_Model_Config:1349`

Cache has been cleaned.

I'm rewriting class **Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default** as followes:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <eav>
           <rewrite>
               <entity_attribute_frontend_default>
                 Namespace_FormValidator_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default
               </entity_attribute_frontend_default>
            </rewrite>
        </eav>
    </models>
</global>
```

And add the file in 
**app/code/local/Namespace/FormValidator/Model/Eav/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/Default.php**

```
class Namespace_FormValidator_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default 
{

}
```

Comment: check your log file

Answer (score 1):

You did not define your own model in config.xml, Magento does not know about the model of your extension. Add this to your config.xml:

```
<global>
    <models>

        <namespace_formvalidator>
            <class>Namespace_FormValidator_Model</class>
        </namespace_formvalidator>

        <eav>
           <rewrite>
               <entity_attribute_frontend_default>
                 Namespace_FormValidator_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default
               </entity_attribute_frontend_default>
            </rewrite>
        </eav>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: It was defined, I just copied a small part of the config.

Comment: Ah, good you found it. Whitespace issues are lovely :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the rewrite should be on one line, so:

`<entity_attribute_frontend_default>Namespace_FormValidator_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default</entity_attribute_frontend_default>`